# Blender loop cut e boolean doesn't work together. How to fix this ? How to create an arc on plane of loop cut?

Tags: modifiers, edit-mode, workflow

I'm trying to reconstruct a real structure, and the whole structure so far has been obtained from a simple plan through the '' loop cut '' system. Which on some occasions is bringing me several problems such as double edges or vertices (easily solved but frustrating) and in this exact case in the construction of arcs.
Question :

1. Is there a way in the loop cut system or in general a method to derive from the only plane I have, an arch, curved or oblique shapes? Obviously to attach them perfectly to the support surface.
2. Also if I try to pierce the plane through an external object and therefore a full semi-circle, the boolean modifier doesn't work or creates ghost artifacts or nothing. (Also tried merged with the "array" modifier).
3. In any case, any other faster or safer method to build this kind of shapes even in a simultaneous way is accepted.

I hope you have the answer to my mistakes.

4. Another thing sometimes after having knocked down some walls and rejoined the vertices to recompose some facades using the "F" FILL key, I can't execute a new loop cut, for example in the walls above the selected arches.

------------ NEW --------

5. I have added some screenshots. In the last two I show you how I had to solve. By deleting the wall, I manually inserted an external arch to the structure and joined later.
   The only problem is that then I have to rebuild the wall, vertex by vertex, because otherwise, graphic artifacts would be created.
6. So the questions always remain the same,
   that is, if you know other methods to build in series using certain measures between the created objects. and why the boolean modifier doesn't work like in this example. (it doesn't work even using an external object, the subtraction is seen in Edit Mode but not in Object and not in Render.)

[Solution?]
I solved it like this in the end, but it is very laborious. (fig.7)
While if I had managed to pierce a plane already dissected by loop cut, it would have been better, and less tiring, but the boolean modifier didn't work.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Could you please use paragraphs to make your question easier to read?

Comment: Sure. So that's good? 

Comment: Much better, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure that responds to your question for some other reason.

[image]

But to keep things simple, you can make a hole in the wall, and place the windows in it as a separated object (you can join them later if needed):

[image]

[image]

Comment: i have a single mesh, a plan, drawn up through the loop cut instrument, how do I do with precise measures?

Comment: I don't know what it to be precise in your context. If you've the measure of a windows, their amount, make a cut/hole in consequence. Or the opposite: start from the hole size and make the windows. You can upload (a part of) your model if you want to that we can have a closer look.

Comment: As you can see I have a single mesh divided into many parts, part of the questions are about a method to generate these round windows from a single extruded mesh. how did you create the ones you made? i load the file

Comment: how do i load it? lol

Comment: The usual way is to use this site http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste the obtained link here or in your question..

Comment: ok, thanks. I load it.

Comment: Hello @Albizz. I've given a quick look at it. Any reason why the locations of the windows are so uneven (not aligned to the world coordinates at all)? I mean, from top view all seems 90° angles but coordinates are shifted from global world coordinates)

Comment: i'm not sure I know what you mean, if you can explain it better and if it's a mistake to explain it.

Comment: For instance, at the second floor of the central part, the left most window has on its top left Z=11.5777 cm and the top right of the same window has Z = 11.5479 cm. Is that wanted ?

Comment: no, some measures I don't know why it seems they moved during my long modifications. I created the structure by just doing loop cuts, so I don't know how to fix these micro differences. I'd do it one at a time I'd go crazy. What advice, can you help me? what about the other questions you asked?

Comment: Albizz, if you make the main parts aligned to the world coordinates, I think what I suggested in he answer should work very well without gaps in between. Just make the walls (only five) well aligned.

Comment: I propose (but not for today as it is late here), to show some steps for doing it. Either as answer here or in chat if you want.

Comment: You must understand that the structure has many parts and many vertices, I cannot understand exactly what you are referring to, I have not even found the central windows you were talking about with differences in sizes.
I think there are undoubtedly errors of measurement, but I don't understand what you are referring to, you should be clearer and more specific, because I don't know what you're talking about or where to act.
thanks, because this is useless for me, I do not solve anything on a practical level.

Comment: Man, ok. Just trying to help... all is just matter of coordinates alignment on *your* model.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that I don't know how the coordinates align :'D and I don't know what you mean by 'main parts'. lol

Comment: This is what I mean about uneven coordinates: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YUQJ.png . I have to quit here soon. If needed, ask me tomorrow

Comment: ok look, just that point is irrelevant as it is a wall created later to adapt to the situation of the arch below. which insertion (of the arc) gave me several problems at the mesh level. So I wrote several questions about creating arched windows on a loop cut plane. Since the boolean didn't work.

Comment: I had to manually disassemble the wall to insert the outer arch. in the file that I have now loaded there should be a different situation but I always think with some underlying problems. In any case if you are available tomorrow I will be happy to hear how in that case, align the main parts to the global coordinates, or is it just a way of saying that the wall is crooked? Because the problem is not only what you can see from the advertisement. :'D :(

Comment: another problem that is specified is that the loop cut is not always allowed on every wall I create. this causes me to sometimes be unable to align things. consequently it leads me to throw everything down and rebuild from scratch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116263/discussion-between-lemon-and-albizz).